# What do you call such an object?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

I would like to know if there is a name for an object $X$ in a (finitely complete and cocomplete) category $\mathcal{C}$ which has the following property:

> $X$ is non-empty and for every sub-object $Y$ of $X$ (by which I mean $Y \cong Y\times_  X Y$), either $Y$ is empty, or $Y=X$.

By non-empty I mean not initial.

Comment: What does "empty" mean ?

Comment: ...not initial. I have edited the question.

Comment: I would suggest an *atom*.

Comment: See this: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simple+object I'm not sure this property has a name, it's equivalent to being simple if your category is abelian.

Comment: The categories I need this definition for are far from abelian...These objects should behave a bit like the connected components in topology. There is an entry under the name "connected object" in nLab, but it is not clear to me if my definition can be extracted from that..

Comment: In most categories this seems like too strong a condition to be interesting. For example, the point is the only topological space satisfying this condition, but of course there are many connected spaces that aren't points.

Comment: I'm in agreement with the term *atom*; cf https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/atom

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone. What if $\mathcal{C}$ has even more structure, but still is not abelian, say it is a Grothendieck topos. Is there a name for these objects in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a partial order on the objects of $\mathcal{C}$ by declaring that $X \le Y$ if there exists a monomorphism $X \to Y$, i.e. if $X$ can be viewed as a subobject of $Y$. Then the initial object is the least element of $\operatorname{ob}\mathcal{C}$, and an object satisfies your condition exactly when it is an [atom](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/atom) for this partial order. So I guess you can call these objects "atoms".

If your category is abelian, then this is equivalent to being a [simple object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simple+object), a better-known property of objects. If the category is not abelian then the conditions are no longer equivalent (the $n$Lab mentions the example of the category of groups: a simple group has no nontrivial quotients, i.e. it has no nontrivial *normal* subgroups, but it can still have non-normal subgroups).

This has actually little to do with being a [connected object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connected+object): in the category of topological spaces, an object is connected in the categorical sense iff it is connected as a space (fortunately). But only a singleton space has no nontrivial subspace.